# Making a counting sum in jQuery each

Tags: jquery

How can I count in a jQuery each function?

```
<script>
    ajax();
    function ajax(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"ChinaWeather.json",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(index, item){ 
                    var sum = 1;
                    $('#countryweatherwrap').append('<div id="countryweather' + sum + '">' + data[index].season + 'Temperatuur: ' +
                        data[index].temperature+' °C <br />' + '<div style="height:'+ data[index].temperature*5.50  +'px;width:100%;border:1px solid #000; background-color:yellow"></div></div>'
                        );  
                    });
            }
        })
    }   
</script>
```

At the moment the code returns `<div id="countryweather">` in every loop. I want it to count so it returns `<div id="countryweather2">`, `<div id="countryweather3">` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. Move `var sum` outside the each loop ( make it global ) 
b. Increment the value of `sum` by 1 via `++;`

```
<script>        
    ajax();
    function ajax(){        
        $.ajax({
            url:"ChinaWeather.json",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){
                var sum = 1;
                $.each(data, function(index, item){                    
                    $('#countryweatherwrap').append('<div id="countryweather' + sum + '">' + data[index].season + 'Temperatuur: ' +
                        data[index].temperature+' °C <br />' + '<div style="height:'+ data[index].temperature*5.50  +'px;width:100%;border:1px solid #000; background-color:yellow"></div></div>'                      
                        );  
                      sum++;
                    });
            }
        })
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: Based on what the OP wants, I would recommend declaring sum inside the success callback (the line just before `$.each`).

Comment: Agreed. That makes sense. +1

Comment: @DinoMyte Thanks for answering! I haven't programmed with jQuery for awhile, I didn't know it could be that simple!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    $('#countryweatherwrap').append('<div id="countryweather' + (index+1) + '">' + data[index].season + 'Temperatuur: ' + data[index].temperature + ' °C <br />' + '<div style="height:' + data[index].temperature * 5.50 + 'px;width:100%;border:1px solid #000; background-color:yellow"></div></div>');
});
```

That has an index starting at `0` so add `1`.